# Reload browser-sync RewriteRules when updating files

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to rewrite HTML of a site loaded through BrowserSync proxy.

I have a:

- ./src/search.txt -- contains regular expression match
- ./build/replace.txt -- contains the replacement HTML for the web page

I want the browserSync to reload each time either of these files are changed.

My gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('readRegEx', function() {
    search_text = fs.readFileSync("./src/search.txt", "utf-8").toString();
    replace_text = fs.readFileSync("./build/replace.txt");
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['readRegEx'], function() {
    browserSync({
        files: ['./src/search.txt','./build/replace.txt'],
        proxy: {
            target: "http://www.example.com"
        },
        rewriteRules: [
            {
                match: new RegExp(search_text,"g"),
                once: true,
                fn: function (match) {
                    return replace_text;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

This ALMOST works.

It reads the /src/search.txt and loads the (regex) and then it replaces it with the contents of /build/replace.txt.

But it only works once. So if I update **search.txt** or **replace.txt**, then browserSync reloads BUT the **rewriteRules** bit doesn't run again.

Is there a way to tell rewriteRules in browserSync to run again when files are updated?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the files every time.

```js
    gulp.task('readRegEx', function() {
        search_text = fs.readFileSync("./src/search.txt", "utf-8").toString();
        replace_text = fs.readFileSync("./build/replace.txt");
    });

    gulp.task('browser-sync', ['readRegEx'], function() {
        browserSync({
            files: ['./src/search.txt','./build/replace.txt'],
            proxy: {
                target: "http://www.example.com"
            },
            rewriteRules: [
                {
                    match: new RegExp(fs.readFileSync("./src/search.txt", "utf-8").toString(), "g"),
                    once: true,
                    fn: function (match) {
                        return fs.readFileSync("./build/replace.txt");
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```